# Does pi have every possible string of combinations?

Tags: pi

I was wondering if Pi has every single possible string of combinations because of its infinite possibilities.

Comment: This is utterly open, but $\pi$ as well as $e$ and every algebraic irrational number, is assumed to be normal (which is an even stronger property, namely that every string occurs with the expected frequency in long terms), moreover it is assumed that the normality holds in every base (which is called absolutely normal). In reality, almost nothing has been proven, not even that $\pi$ does not eventually consist of only the digits $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The incredible large number of digits that have been calculated however support the conjecture that $\pi$ is normal. It has been shown that each digit sequence with $11$ digits occurs in the decimal expansion of $\pi$.